# In the shell, why does "2>err&" allows a script to be run in the background?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, redirect, io-redirection

for example I have a python script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.7
import time

n=0
while True:
    print(n)
    n = n + 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

If I execute the `$test.py` in shell like so, I can hit `Ctrl+C` to cancel the script at any time.
but if I execute the script like this: `$test.py 2>err&`, the only way I can stop the script is using `kill` command from another terminal.

I can't find any reference to `2>err&`, what does it really mean?

Comment: It is not the redirection, it is the `&` that executes the command in the background. It just happens to be written here without a space after the redirection of stderr. i.e., if you run `test.py &` it will also run in the background. The `2>` redirects file descriptor number 2, which is stderr, to the destination named afterwards, here `err`.

Comment: It would be better written as `2>err &` -- less confusion that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2>err&` is not one thing.

`2>err` means to redirect standard error to the file named `err`. You can do this for foreground and background commands, and it has nothing to do with whether you can kill the process with <kbd>Ctl-C</kbd>.

`&` at the end of a command means to run it in the background. Keyboard interrupts are only sent to the foreground process group, so commands in the background are not killed with <kbd>Ctl-C</kbd> (this assumes job control is in effect, which it almost always is for interactive shells). You can use the `fg` command to switch a background process to foreground.